# Jquery Toggle function not working!

Tags: html, jquery-ui, toggle, jquery

I have made a little Jquery after thinking a lot (as I'm new to this), and found it not working properly! See, in my code I suppose to click on the element which is set by the var `trigger` and the element which is set by the var `obj` should `fadeToggle()` but when I click on the `trigger` for one moment it is shown (just a second barely!) and then disappears! I just don't what is going wrong, but you can have a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/XMZVe/) (to see the problem). And by the way code is down here --

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                   var trigger = 'trigger' ;
                   var obj = 'slide' ;

                    $('.' + trigger).click(function () {
                       $('.' + obj).fadeToggle(); 
                    }); 
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            div.head
            {
             background: #000;
             opacity: 0.7;
             color: #fff;
             font-weight: bold;
             font-size: 12px;
             font-family: segoe ui;
             padding: 5px 5px; 
            }
            div.head a
            {
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #fff;  
            }

            div.slide
            {
             display: none;
             background: #000;
             opacity: 0.7;
             color: #fff;
             font-weight: bold;
             font-size: 12px;
             font-family: segoe ui;
             padding: 5px 5px;  
            }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="head">
            <a class="trigger" href="">Click Me!</a>
            <div class="slide">
                Hi Friends!
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On jsFiddle it is showing me the following error (only when you click RUN before doing something on the RESULT field.) --

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

Can anyone help me out with this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your link is being followed. You can [prevent that from happening](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) like this:

```
 $('.' + trigger).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();   
     $('.' + obj).fadeToggle(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.slide').fadeToggle();
});
```

Also, you do do not need to have 2 ready functions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

is the same as

```
$(function () {
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/RfgkU/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  $(document).ready(function () {

$(function(){}); is good enough to specify the commands must run on page load. This also works consistently across all browsers.

Also specify  e.preventDefault(); as the first line in your click function to tell jQuery to ignore the click on the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `display: none` attribute that causes this beaviour.
Try putting it inline:

```
<div class="slide" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: did't read the lsat lines of your question.. yes, as Karim says, you should also add e.preventDefault() to your click function